# Magento 1.9.1 Cannot initialize the indexer process for Product Price only

Tags: indexing, magento-1.9

Facing indexing issue in Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 Flat Product Price is OFF. Refer Sceenshot : http://prntscr.com/be7veh

I have followed below mentioned links still facing the same issue:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/Cannot-reindex-Category-Products-Index-Process-Information/td-p/1603

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114178/there-was-a-problem-with-reindexing-process-rebuild-catalog-product-fulltext-s/114181

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24729/there-was-a-problem-with-reindexing-process

[Magento - There was a issue with reindexing process - Catalog Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927020/magento-there-was-a-issue-with-reindexing-process-catalog-products)

[Cannot initialize the indexer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641799/cannot-initialize-the-indexer-process)

Command output screenshot : prntscr.com/be81c0

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into the site using ssh, then go the the magento root directory and use the command 'php shell/indexer.php --reindexall'

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins alter the DB structure.
try the following script and check the error (simply paste this code in footer and run).

```
    $indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
    foreach ($indexCollection as $index)
    {
        try
        {
            $index->reindexAll();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            print_r($e->getMessage());

        }
    }
```